# Need help modifying an echo statement to accommodate for another echo statement within it

Tags: php

I am building a Bootstrap carousel gallery to display post images. I have it working for the most part, but I am running into an issue with my PHP repeating the images within the `.item div`. After checking the view source HTML, I found out what the issue is and I know what to do to fix it, but I am having trouble executing it.

My issue is working with another echo statement that would need to be nested in my main echo statement.

I've been looking around on here and some other sites for working with echos in other echo statements, but I can't seem to execute it properly. I'm newer to PHP still and am probably missing a series of '' and/or "" when I'm trying to make things work. If anyone could help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it.

What I need to do is make this code:

```
<div class="<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'item active':'item';  ?>" align="center">
  <img src='admin/images/".$imrow->img_name."' width='auto' height='auto'/>
</div>
```

Exist within the `echo "..."` in the code below so all the images can exist independently of one another.

```
           <?php 
            $imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$id'";
            $q2 = $db->query($imsql);
            if($q2->num_rows>0){
              while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()){  
              echo "<img src='admin/images/".$imrow->img_name."' width='auto' height='auto'/>";
            }
          }
            ?>
```

**EDIT FOR FUTURE REFERENCE**

Here is my code within my `carousel-inner div` prior to it working:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <?php
        $i = 0;
        for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++):
      ?>

   <div class="<?php echo $i == 0 ? 'item active':'item';  ?>" align="center">

       <?php 
        $imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$id'";
        $q2 = $db->query($imsql);
        if($q2->num_rows>0){
          while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()){  
    echo '<img src="admin/images/' . $imrow->img_name . '" width="auto" height="auto"/>';
    echo '</div>';
        }
      }
        ?>
     </div>

      <?php
        $i++;
        endfor;
      ?>
    </div>
```

Here is the version that accomplishes what I need:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

          <?php
            $i = 0;
            for ($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++):
          ?>

           <?php 
            $imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$id'";
            $q2 = $db->query($imsql);
            if($q2->num_rows>0){
              while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()){  
                echo '<div class="' . ($i == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item') . '" align="center">';
        echo '<img src="admin/images/' . $imrow->img_name . '" width="auto" height="auto"/>';
        echo '</div>';
            }
          }
            ?>

          <?php
            $i++;
            endfor;
          ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have really very little idea what you mean. Your example is unclear - it looks like the `img` tag is already within your `div`, not the other way round. Perhaps what you need to do is make a HTML string as a variable which you build up gradually in a series of statements, rather than echoing everything immediately as you generate it? Then you've got more control over the output and can vary it a bit more. Echo within echo makes no sense. echo sends finished output to the client. If it's not finshed, don't echo it yet.

Comment: are both these segments in the same document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood what you are trying to achieve, but here's my guess:

```
<?php 
$imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$id'";
$q2 = $db->query($imsql);
if($q2->num_rows>0){
    $i = 0;
    while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<div class="' . ($i++ === 0 ? 'item active' : 'item') . '" align="center">';
        echo '<img src="admin/images/' . $imrow->img_name . '" width="auto" height="auto"/>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

That code is not beautiful at all but I tried to just make your current code work. Of course there are many other ways to achieve this. Of course you need a counter `$i` which was not included in your code sample.

Here is another option how you can display the opening div with the correct css class. Always use item as a class, only add active if needed:

```
echo '<div class="item' . ($i++ === 0 ? ' active' : '') . '" align="center">';
```

Comment: where is $i being generated?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to do. I think I was having truble how to figure out the `. ($i == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item') .` portion and didn't try the parenthesis around it. It makes total sense.

Comment: @Juakali92 I realized I never included where I was generating `$i` from since it was further up in my coding and I forgot to grab it. I will modify my question to include it for other people that may find this question and its answers useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
echo '<div class="'.($i == 0 ? 'item active':'item').'" align="center"><img src=\'admin/images/\''.$imrow->img_name.'\' width=\'auto\' height=\'auto\'/></div>'
```

Answer (score -3):

As far as I see you can close the php tag after starting the while loop then add the code that you need and open the php tag again.
E.g.

```
While(true) { ?>
// html or php code here
<?php }
```